# I keep getting this error when trying to create a tabe in Access through vb.net using SQL: OleDbExcetion was unhandled

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

```
 Private Sub CreateTable_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CreateTable.Click
    Dim myConnToAccess As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim mySQLCommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim mySQLStrg As String
    myConnToAccess = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Registers.accdb;")
    myConnToAccess.Open()
    mySQLStrg = "CREATE TABLE" & Tablename1.Text & "([Activity_ID] NUMBER, [Teacher_Name] TEXT, [Pupil_Name] TEXT);"
    mySQLCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(mySQLStrg, myConnToAccess)
    ***mySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()***
```

Error occurs after this statement

```
    MsgBox("Table " & Tablename1.Text & " has been created")
    myConnToAccess.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

put a space after the "CREATE TABLE" to "CREATE TABLE", otherwise, it is becoming

```
"CREATE TABLEYourTable"
```

instead of

```
"CREATE TABLE YourTable"
```

Comment: @Carlos, thanks, but there are plenty out who would have spotted it too.  Also, check out the link above for Help -> Tour, for etiquette on the site and marking questions when they are solved so others too know what worked vs not.